# Elegant/efficient means of sending email with Codeigniter and Sendgrid

Tags: codeigniter, sendgrid

I'm setting up some transactional email fun in our Codeigniter app via integrating with Sendgrid.

I've got things setup and ready to move forward with creating all of the specific transactions/emails, but I was wondering about the most efficient and/or elegant way of doing so.

It seems a bit convoluted to include the appropriate email code in each of the functions. To call a specific function from a clean and separated `email` controller would require me to use AJAX (so as to not cause a redirect).

Is there some way that I'm not considering currently that would help balance things, namely cleanliness and separation along with coherency and ease?

Thanks for any thoughts-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the specifics of your application structure. But you could always create a model function and call that from the functions in your controller.

CodeIgniter also comes with some built in functionality to help you send emails, specifically setting some of your email settings in a config file so you don't have to rewrite that. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. the model idea crossed my mind after i posted, actually. it does seem like the best way to avoid doing ajax requests and mudddying up the controllers. i've got the email config stuff off in an 'email.php' config file, so that's taken care of. i just didn't want all the `..->to()->message..` stuff to clog up my controllers. while it may not be best practice to throw this into a model, i have to create some models for some of these to grab the necessary data so having a few extra lines in the model to send the email seems to be the most efficient way of dealing with it

Comment: just realized i could do another sort of middle ground approach that has the benefit of separating the model and controller work. instead of creating an `email` controller to house all of my email functions, i can just create functions within the specific controller's context that serves as the transactional base. for instance, when someone adds a new project an email needs to be sent out. so, in the `projects` controller, beneath the `addNewProject()` function I can have an `addNewProjectEmail()` which the former function calls `$this->addNewProjectEmail()` and voila!

Comment: This ended up being more of a conceptual question than an actual, specific instance within my coding. Thanks for your input and trying to help out, accepting answer as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a blog post about this not too terribly long ago.  Have a look at this:

> http://blog.sendgrid.com/using-sendgrid-with-php-codeigniter/

Essentially, codeigniter comes with an awesome email library that makes it easy to send stuff over SMTP, so I just show you how to hook into that.